# Data binding between xml file and winform

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to build an UI using winform that has an xml file as a data source.
The xml file has somewhat complex schema. the ui has a data grid that shows the data in tabular format. 
I am looking for a good way to bind the xml data to the UI.
Any input will be appreciated.

Edit 1:
Sorry I did not ask properly first time. 
Here is my xml

```
<group name="Trade" occurrence="0">
      <field name="AcctNum"  l="1739" t="239" r="1922" b="266">31A-90506</field>
      <field name="Desc"  l="133" t="935" r="590" b="962">AMERICAN EXPRESS COMP</field>
      <field name="Shares"  l="1022" t="935" r="1114" b="963">65.00</field>
      <field name="SalesPrice"  l="1733" t="934" r="1879" b="968">3796.06</field>
      <field name="Cost"  l="2111" t="934" r="2251" b="967">2648.41</field>
      <field name="Acquired" l="1192" t="934" r="1332" b="963">2010-10-27</field>
      <field name="Sold"  l="1354" t="934" r="1499" b="964">2012-05-15</field>
      <field name="WashSale"  l="2592" t="934" r="2664" b="962">0.00</field>
      <field name="Noncovered"  l="2997" t="701" r="3082" b="728">X</field>
    </group>
    <group name="Trade" occurrence="1">
      <field name="Desc"  l="135" t="1088" r="513" b="1116">COCA COLA COMPANY</field>
      <field name="Shares"  l="1022" t="1087" r="1115" b="1116">30.00</field>
      <field name="SalesPrice"  l="1733" t="1087" r="1873" b="1121">2243.71</field>
      <field name="Cost"  l="2115" t="1087" r="2257" b="1120">1715.65</field>
      <field name="Acquired"  l="1191" t="1087" r="1332" b="1117">2010-09-01</field>
      <field name="Sold"  l="1355" t="1087" r="1500" b="1117">2012-05-31</field>
      <field name="WashSale"  l="2593" t="1087" r="2664" b="1116">0.00</field>
    </group>
```

each group is a row in my data grid and each field is eqivalent to a cell. I just need to show field element  value in the cell. rest of the info is necessary for further processing.

I have created an C# class from the xml and deserialize the xml. Now I need to bind this data to the data grid. Please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 2:
I wanting to display the data in a data grid on a winform. As I have mentioned in edit 1 
each group is a row in my data grid and each field is eqivalent to a cell. I just need to show field element  value in the cell. rest of the info is necessary for further processing. 
How do I do the binding for the group  object

Comment: Show the schema of your `xml` and show also how would data look like in a tabular format in a `Datagrid`. But most of all show the code that you have done so far.

Comment: Create class of your item in `xml`(one row in table in `Winforms` ). Properties of the class bind to column of the table. Then load Collection of that class objects from `xml`. Show some code about how you read `xml`?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please remove th ehold or let me know if  anything else needed.thanks

Comment: @lumaC it is good to have the code, but you still have not asked a specific question.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Edited again. Please let me know if I need to be more specific.